# disable form elements in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component as following :

```
component('page', {
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'page-component.html',
    controller: 'PageController',
    controllerAs: 'pc'
});
```

And this is how I'm using it :

```
<page>
    <page-section section-id="1">
        <div>
            <ng-include src="'panelX.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </page-section>
    <page-section section-id="2">
        <div>
            <ng-include src="'panelY.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </page-section>
</page>
```

In this component controller I want to disable all form elements (inputs, buttons, textareas...), so I did as following :

```
$("form").find('input, textarea, button, select, button').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

The problem I have is that this code is executed before `panelX.html` and `panelY.html` are loaded.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

Since the application is big and it contains hundreds of forms I don't want to touch the html code, I only want the code inside the page directive to work for all forms in the application.

Comment: several ways to deal with this, simplest might be using the ng-init in the last element in that form. When the element loads it will trigger the function, in that function do what you did.

Comment: you can use onload with ng-include

Comment: @DanteTheSmith the problem is that the application is too big and it has hundreds of foms in it, but all the forms are always inside the page directive so I wanted to implement a code in the page directive that will affect all the forms in the application.

Comment: $viewContentLoaded event might be of use. It triggers when ng-view is loaded fully, even on reloads.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith I'm using `ngComponentRouter` for routing so `$viewContentLoaded` wont work in this case.

Comment: Angular is not Jquery. You are not supposed to take some html and then magically modify it.